# Can I script my mac to reboot and login at a specified time?

Tags: macos, applescript, script, command-line

Can I use shell scripts, AppleScript, or some other form of scripting to get my mac to reboot and login at a specified time?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- use System Preferences/Energy Settings to define shutdown/restart times
- run `sudo shutdown -r 23:45` to automatically reboot every night
- combine the second option with a cron/launchd job to reschedule the reboot daily (or just call `shutdown -r now` from cron/launchd)

You also can set one user to auto-login after reboot in System Preferences/Users & Groups. But at least use a password-protected screen saver in this case, otherwise anybody can walk up to your computer after a reboot and start using it.